# Create a Trigger to output/append mssql results to a file

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm using mssql and I want to create a trigger to append any added data from a table to a file. I'm using express so using the wizard is not an option since it does not save in express edition. The table is small and does not receive data often. The table essentially is used to log notes on a products life test. More or less I want the results in a file for our team and or customers. Thanks in advance for any help on the matter.

Comment: mysql != sql-server.  Change the tag or the body of the question.

Comment: Generally, triggers shouldn't access any resources outside of their own database. If possible, just populate another table that contains pending rows and then, separately from the trigger, run a separate task that pulls rows from that table, puts them in the file and then removes them from the table. This avoids causing the original insert/update/delete activity from being affected by external problems.